# Change click event in Bootstrap custom tab

Tags: tabs, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap custom tab. And instead of just menu names I have multiple select tags and date range picker. And I want to open tab's content not on click on that drop-down select, but I want the click to be triggered, when user will choose from that drop-down list.

Do you have any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
So this is bootstrap custom tab

```
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <label class="control-label text-white">tab1</label>
                <a href="#tab1" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                    <select class="form-control select2">
                        <option>All</option>
                        <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
                            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
                            <option value="CA">California</option>
                            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
                            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group text-left">
                    <label class="control-label text-white">tab2</label>
                    <a href="#tab2" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"
                       aria-expanded="false">
                        <select class="form-control text-white" name="country">
                            <option>All</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group text-left">
                    <label class="control-label text-white">tab3</label>
                    <a href="#tab3" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                    <select class="form-control text-white" name="country">
                        <option>All</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have select tags on each tab, I want to trigger click event when user select item form that select drop-down list. Currently when I click on select tag, without selecting any item, tab content appears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to SO! please support your question with some code examples

Comment: Hi @Deepark, thanks in advance. I have made update.

Comment: can't see any dropdown in your given code snippet